# Is it possible to plot a function's value along a curve using different color?

Tags: plotting, color

I have a curve in 3D space which is green curve in the following picutre

[image]

The code for generating the curve is as follows:

```
g[x_, y_, z_] := x + y + z;
h[x_, y_, z_] := x^2 + y^2 + z^2;
s = -5;
ContourPlot3D[{g[x, y, z] == 0, h[x, y, z] == 24}, {x, -s, s}, {y, -s,
   s}, {z, -s, s}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", Mesh -> None, 
 BoundaryStyle -> {{1, 2} -> {Thick, Green}}]
```

I was wondering, if it is possible to depict the value of the function $2 x + y z$ on this curve with colors? Like when the color is darker the the value is larger, when the color is lighter then the value is smaller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the boundary using `g` as the `MeshFunctions` option value:

```
boundary = ContourPlot3D[h[x, y, z] == 24, {x, -s, s}, {y, -s, s}, {z, -s, s}, 
   MeshFunctions -> (g[#, #2, #3] &),
   Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   MeshStyle -> Green,
   ContourStyle -> None];
```

You can post-process `boundary` to inject desired colors using `VertexColors`:

```
coloredboundary = Normal[boundary] /. 
     Line[x_] :> {Tube[x, .3, VertexColors -> Hue /@ Rescale[2 # + #2 #3 & @@@ x]]};   

Show[ContourPlot3D[{g[x, y, z] == 0, h[x, y, z] == 24}, {x, -s, s}, {y, -s, s}, {z, -s, s}, 
  Mesh -> None], 
 coloredboundary]
```

[image]

Replace `Hue` with your favorite color function.

Alternatively, you can process `boundary` to convert the `Line` object into a [`BSplineFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BSplineFunction.html) and use it with [`ParametricPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html) with the option `ColorFunction`:

```
bsF = Cases[Normal[boundary], Line[x_] :> BSplineFunction[x], All][[
   1]];

coloredboundary2 = ParametricPlot3D[bsF[t], {t, 0, 1}, 
    ColorFunction -> (Hue[2 # + #2 #3] &)] /. Line[a_, b_] :> Tube[a, .3, b];

Show[ContourPlot3D[{g[x, y, z] == 0, h[x, y, z] == 24}, {x, -s, s}, {y, -s, s}, {z, -s, s},
 Mesh -> None], 
 coloredboundary2, ViewPoint -> Front]
```

[image]